# Cordova 6.1.1 overscroll and UI bounce IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, ionic2

I am working on Ionic 2 having `Cordova 6.1.1`. My app overscrolls for a down scroll at the top of the page and bounces on a text box focus (when keyboard opens).

This seems to be a generic problem and has some solutions for earlier versions of `cordova`.

The following preferences are set correctly in my `config.xml`.

```
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

They do not work for `Cordova 6.1.1` or above (6.2.0) !!

Thanks.

Comment: Does that bounce on keyboard open ?

Comment: Yes. It bounces on keyboard open. Edited my question for the same

Comment: Try re installing keyboard plugin.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I am OOO for a few days. I'll try the solution and get back.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the exact same setup. ionic 2 and set the three options without any luck

Comment: I couldnt find a good solution, so did some CSS tweeks so that the bounce looks less bad.